# Why does new sametime message kill Notes and Designer

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, sametime

About once a day, when I get pinged via sametime and it causes Notes and Designer to crash immediately.  If I am looking at the screen, I can see the sender and part of the message before the NDS message comes up that Notes has crashed.

I am a developer, not an admin, and hope to troubleshoot this myself or at least have information to give to the Notes Admin and/or desktop support.

Running Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 with 6GB Ram. 64bit O/S.  Notes Designer 9.01FP3.  Worth noting is this is a virtual machine.

Note: I am always in designer when it crashes, not Notes itself.

Comment: First of all collect exact cause of the crash - analyze that NSD. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24019151

Comment: Good suggestion @Frantisek, I usually just cancel out of the NSD, but next time will take some time to look at the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steve I don't think this is a stackoverflow question. 
But I believe that the problem is related to increased JVM memory for the designer. I've turned of sametime inside the client and is running the external client = problem solved

Comment: Yes, I knew the question was borderline when I created it, but your answer here really helps me out so I am glad I asked it :)  I will ask my admin if I can get an external client for sametime.  I didn't know there was one.  I will also analyze the NSD if it crashes before then as @Frantisek suggests.